# Как убрать Global Tint у Navigation Bar

Tags: swift, xcode

Столкнулся с проблемой
Создал Navigation Bar и вставил в него item, а в item поместил логотип
Но проблема вот в чем, логотип разноцветный, а global tint автоматом закрашивает его в один цвет, свойство No Color отсутствует
Можно ли как то не закрашивать логотип полностью?
Подскажите как это сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если ваш логотип это просто `UIImage` и вам нужно отобразить его в оригинальных цветах, попробуйте использовать `.alwaysOriginal` `RenderingMode`.

Пример

```
let img = UIImage(named:"myImage")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
```

Варианты режимов рендеринга изображений можно посмотреть по ссылке [UIImage.RenderingMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/renderingmode)

Comment: Прошу прощения что ответил так поздно, но это не помогло

Comment: Добавьте в пост код, как вы делаете navigation bar item